# Complex monic polynomial $f(z)$ with $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1.$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_{0}$ be a complex polynomial such that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1.$ I have to prove that $f(z)=z^{n}.$

I tried it as

As $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$ we must have coefficient $a_{0},a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}$ to be zero because by triangular inequality $$|z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_{0}|\leq 1+|a_{n-1}|+\cdot\cdot\cdot+|a_{0}|$$ so all of the coefficient $a_{0},a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}$ to be zero. But it is not exact proof. Please suggest me further improvement. Thanks

Comment: But again its does't  gives complete answer..

Comment: @neelkanth Why do you say that?

Comment: $$
f(\mathrm{e}^{it})\,\mathrm{e}^{-int}=1,\quad\text{for all $t\in[0,2\pi]$,}
$$  or equivalently 
$$
f(z)=z^n,
$$

Comment: How this line????

Comment: @neelkanth That line is $f(z) \cdot z^{-n}=1$ for $z=e^{it}\,$.

Comment: Yes thankyou........